# Reading 3 Delimited Files passed as Parameters to a AWK Script and parse the 3 Files and store in 3 different arrays

Tags: bash, shell, awk

File 1:

```
A|sam|2456|8901

B|kam|5678|9000

C|pot|4567|8000
```

---

File 2:

```
X|ter|2456|8901

Y|mar|5678|9000

Z|poi|4567|8000
```

---

File 3:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Coumn4
```

---

Now i want this 3 Files to be passed as parameters to the GNU Awk Script as below -

```
awk -f script.awk file1 file2 file3
```

---

Script i  have written are able to handle only 2 Files but not able to handle the 3rd file. Pleas help.

---

### script.awk

```
BEGIN     { # setup file separator and sorting:
        FS=OFS="|" 
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
      }

# skip header lines
FNR == 1  { next }

# store first file
(FNR==NR) { f1[$5]=$0
            # skip processing of other rules and 
            # read the next line from input
            next
         }

# store second file
          { f2[$5]=$0
            if( ! ($5 in f1)) {
                f1[$5] = ""
            }
         }

END       { 
        for( k in f1) {
            split( f1[k], arr1, "|")

            for( c = 1; c <= length( f1[ k ] ); c++ ) {
                    print arr1[c]
                }
            }
         for( k in f2) {

            split( f2[k], arr2, "|")
            for( c = 1; c <= length( f2[ k ] ); c++ ) {
                    print arr2[c]
                }
            }
        }
      }
```

My Objective is the Read the 3rd File also in the same code in the print in the similar way as the printing is handled in the above code.

Note : Would be good if anyone can keep the similar Code structure as above and just include the reading and printing of the 3rd File.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Wanting to read the files based on the Delimeter and print the data thats it. The above code does tit for 2 files but i want to incorporate the 3rd file also and process and print like the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code is more complicated than it has to be. It could be written as just:

```
BEGIN     { # setup file separator and sorting:
    ...
      }

# skip header lines
FNR == 1  { next }

ARGIND==1 { f1[$5]=$0; next }
ARGIND==2 { f2[$5]=$0; f1[$5] }

END       { 
    ...
      }
```

I assume you can see the obvious extension to add a 3rd file. The above requires GNU awk for ARGIND and PROCINFO[] which you're already using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ARGV` array to process multiple files like this:

```
function disp() {
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      print FILENAME " :: " FNR " :: " $i
   print ""
}

BEGIN { # setup file separator and sorting:
   FS=OFS="|" 
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
}

# process first file
ARGV[1] == FILENAME {
   disp()
}
# process second file
ARGV[2] == FILENAME {
   disp()
}
# process third file
ARGV[3] == FILENAME {
   disp()
}
```

Comment: Does here FILENAME signifies my actual filename that i am passing?

Comment: i tried with a dry run with the Below code and it looks like not working. Please find below code i tried with -

Comment: the top of the code remains the same the end i wrote as - # store third file

    ARGV[3] == FILENAME {
       f3[$5]=$0
    }

    END       { 
            split( f3[1], arr3, "|")
                for( c = 1; c <=5; c++ ) {
                        print arr3[c]
                    
                    }
                }

Comment: I used f3[1] in split as always by content in 3rd file expected to be 1 Line

Comment: Edit your question and show your expected output using your sample input data.

Comment: See updated answer and check output. It will dump rows/fields from all the 3 files.

Comment: If she has PROCINFO then she's using gawk and then she  can test ARGIND instead of FILENAME and she can also use multi-dimensional arrays like `arr[FILENAME][FNR]` if necessary to store file contents in an array.